# where are the IFS files coming from and how are they created?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, list

I need to manage a SharePoint 2010 site, and I'm also learning SP:) btw: I'm also Site collection administrator.

I've understood that each **list** has 3 displays forms.

- Newform.aspx
- Editform.aspx
- Displayform.aspx

When I goto a list in In SharePoint Designer than I see these 3 forms in the Forms view (right below). But for some lists I also see editifs.aspx,newifs.aspx,displayifs.aspx. So in totally 6.

## so my questions are:

1. Where are these xxxifs (e.g. editifs.aspx) files coming from?
2. How are they created and what is the purpose?
3. When I look in SPD the Default display is EditForm.aspx (Yes),
   DispForm.aspx(YES), NewForm.aspx (YES), but what does it make or
   does it come when I click on Edit button on the list item (in the
   list) it opens editfs.aspx form (I see that in the URL)?

I googled and found that it's related to infopath, but what I need to know how is how is it created what it is etc.

can someone please give some explanation, especially on the 3rd question I have.

thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you choose an option in Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2010 to customize these forms in InfoPath 2010. When you do this, you create and publish an InfoPath Form Template, or XSN file, which is used with a new set of list forms: displayifs.aspx, editifs.aspx, and newifs.aspx.

Read the below office article for compelte details.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-designer-help/edit-list-forms-using-infopath-2010-in-sharepoint-designer-HA101631624.aspx

Comment: thank you the link was very useful and accepted. Just 3 more related question :), ( 1 ) When I edit it opens InfoPath forms I make changes in that form, then I save and publish it. During save it propose me a XSN file. I just save the XSN file then publish it. But what do I need to do with the saved XSN file? can I delete it? ( 2 ) I can get into the IFS files when I click in SPD. why ( 3 ) how to restore back to original state, meaning not using the ifs files just to see the 3 org files only. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The non-standard list-forms are created when you choose to edit the default forms in InfoPath, so instead of deleting the original forms, SharePoint creates 3 additional forms. They could be named to anything, but get the names editifs.aspx, newifs.aspx, and displayifs.aspx when created using the button in the list ribbon called "Edit in InfoPath".

"ifs" stands for InfoPath Forms Service.

What you are seeing in SPD is that SharePoint uses the default list-forms for your list, but you could choose to set one of the custom forms to the default instead if you like to have a custom edit-form for example.